# Perl: check in hash if all entries are equal, get an arbitrary/random key from hash

Tags: perl, hash, comparison

**The goal:** I want to check if all entries in a hash are equal in some manner (here it's the count).

**My nasty solution:**

```
# initialize some fake data
my @list1 = (2, 3);
my @list2 = (1, 2);
my %hash = (12 => \@list1, 22 => \@list2);
# here starts the quest for the key
my $key;
foreach my $a (keys %hash) {
  $key = $a;
}
# some $key is set
# here starts the actual comparision
my $count = scalar(@{%hash{$key}});
foreach my $arr_ref (%hash) {
  my $actcount = scalar(@$arr_ref);
  print "some warning" if $actcount != $count;
}
```

I know I could also store the size in the first iteration of the loop, then I would not need to get the key in advance. But it will cause me a conditional statement in eacht iteration. Thus I like to avoid it.

**The question:**
What is a proper way to get a key from the hash?

**Addition:**
There should be something possible like
(keys %hash)[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my $key = (keys %hash)[0]` should work, or you can force list context by enclosing the scalar you assign to in parentheses:

```
my ($key) = keys %hash;
```

Another way would be to use `each` in scalar context:

```
my $key = each %hash;
```

In the testing loop, you are only interested in values, so don't iterate over the keys, too:

```
for my $arr_ref (values %hash) {
```